# I am getting the error An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://xxxxx/Service/.

Tags: wcf

i am getting this error " An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to `http://xxxxxx/CustomerService`/. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details."

and i cannot proceed further.

How can i resolve this issue and i checked with the Service Logs also and Service Trace viewer also but i didn't understand

Why/When this is happened?

Comment: We'll need to see the code that produced this error.

Comment: Is there any error in the event logs on the server?